# Can I use 'private' as an attribute name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On my `Comment` model I want to have a boolean attribute called `private` for comments that are only meant for the post author.

Can I use that word as an attribute without problem or is it a reserved word or any other reason against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use `is_private`
It indicates that its a Boolean and you don't get confused!